# Swift observe(_:options:changeHandler:) newValue always nil

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, key-value-observing, avcapturedevice

I have this setup to observe value changes for AVCaptureDevice deviceWhiteBalanceGains:

```swift
@objc dynamic var videoDevice:AVCaptureDevice?
private var deviceWBGainsObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

And then in the code,

```swift
deviceWBGainsObservation = videoDevice?.observe(\.deviceWhiteBalanceGains,
                     options: [.old, .new]) {[unowned self] (object, change) in

    NSLog("\(change)")
}
```

Problem is change oldValue and newValue is always nil. This is not the case if I use the traditional key-value observing method `observeValue(forKeypath:...)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can confirm this issue. I've encountered this, too. For now, my workaround is to observe `isAdjustingWhiteBalance` instead (works quite well and almost instantaneous).

Comment: We are observing a similar issue with `AVPlayerItem.duration` and `AVPlayerItem.status` but not with other `AVPlayerItem` properties like `isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp` or `isPlaybackBufferEmpty` 

Comment: The traditional observeValue for keypath has a big problem. Sometimes it crashes by saying no observer is added for keyPath which I can not reproduce. I wish the Swift API for AVPlayer worked.